# Wanting to work somewhere with an option to move, should I tell recruiter?

Tags: professionalism, job-search

Context
- Happily employed for the last 5yrs, love my current company
- Want to move to a new location to be closer to wife's family
- Current company has no presence in the area, pure remote position is not something that would make sense given my desired career path

Considerations
- Compensation at current company is structured such that leaving before June would be very costly
- Current lease expires at the end of Feb 2020 - desired move date is March 2020

Question
As I talk to recruiters for prospective companies (not general recruiters, these people work for the companies in question directly) (all of whom have a presence in the desired metro area) should I mention my desire to first work in my current area and then move to this new area?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Im not sure why you even have to ask.**

You want to move, even have a timeframe set.

**Of course you should tell the recruiters.**

By letting them know, they'll concentrate on finding a way to accomodate your wish without bothering you with offers you'll deny anyways.

*Mind you, some may have issues with integrating you into a team and moving you after merely a year or so.*

Comment: For some clarity, this isnt a general recruiter. I am contacting the companies directly - sorry I didnt add that bit of context, will update